# How to send input to an attached process in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

## Question

I have a test program called `scan` (see code section) that I run in one terminal. The program starts running and asks the user to enter a letter:

```
$ ./scan
Enter a letter
```

In another terminal window, I run gdb and attach to the `scan` process:

```
$ sudo gdb -p `pidof scan`
(gdb)
```

I would like to send contents of a binary file called `payload` as input to the `scan` process. How can I accomplish this in gdb while the process is attached? Is this possible?

## Background

I want to attach to the `scan` process because I want to examine the program's ASLR address space while running. If I run the process directly with gdb (`$ gdb scan`), gdb turns off ASLR and I get consistent addressing.

For example, running `scan` directly with gdb (please note that `...` is truncated output):

```
$ gdb scan
(gdb) info functions
...
0x00000000000005a8  _init
0x00000000000005d0  __stack_chk_fail@plt
0x00000000000005e0  printf@plt
0x00000000000005f0  __isoc99_scanf@plt
...
```

The addresses shown above are the same every time I run gdb this way, which indicates that gdb turns off ASLR. However, when attaching to a process, the addresses always change. On one run:

```
$ sudo gdb -p `pidof scan`
(gdb) info functions
...
0x00005598706305a8  _init
0x00005598706305d0  __stack_chk_fail@plt
0x00005598706305e0  printf@plt
0x00005598706305f0  __isoc99_scanf@plt
```

On another run:

```
0x000055813ccf65a8  _init
0x000055813ccf65d0  __stack_chk_fail@plt
0x000055813ccf65e0  printf@plt
0x000055813ccf65f0  __isoc99_scanf@plt
```

The file `payload` contains a binary payload. I know how to send file contents as input when running gdb normally (e.g. `(gdb) run < payload`), but not when running with an attached process.

I **do not** want to copy/paste these file contents into the terminal that is running`scan`. I also **do not** want to turn off ASLR.

## Things I have tried/read

I have read the [gdb manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) and gdb help commands:

```
(gdb) help
(gdb) help target
(gdb) help attach
(gdb) help obscure
```

Other StackOverflow questions do not ask about sending input to an attached process:

- [Pass File Input and Stdin to gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503045/pass-file-input-and-stdin-to-gdb)
- [How to debug a program that takes user input from stdin with GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104206/how-to-debug-a-program-that-takes-user-input-from-stdin-with-gdb)
- [How to passing input data in GDB mode for programming C. Already passed parameters and run program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705778/how-to-passing-input-data-in-gdb-mode-for-programming-c-already-passed-paramete)

## Code

My entire `scan` program is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char letter[1];
    char buffer[8]; 
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    int result = scanf("%s", letter);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", letter);
}
```

Comment: See [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944979/1983398) on how to enable ASLR when running with gdb.

Comment: That's the answer to the real question. The answer to the XY question might be to have gdb run `close(0); open("payload", O_RDONLY);`

Comment: Simulating terminal input is best done by acting on the terminal device itself, such as by using TIOCSTI if you're on a Unix or Linux system, rather than by poking the target process. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370822/2554472 shows a couple ways to do this.